# AngularJS - How to compile inputs inside form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form declared in the html file. The inputs are generated dynamically.

That means, they are built as strings in javascript and then compiled inside a custom directive in angular.

```
app.directive('customInput', function($compile){
return{
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: true,
  link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    var html = "<input type='text' ng-model='tCtrl.test[$index]' ng-required='required' ng-maxlength='3'/>";
    var el = $compile(html)(scope);
    element.html("");
    element.append(el);
  }
}
});
```

They work fine with my angular code, but the problem is: They are not "recognized" as part of my form. That means, the parent FORM element does not change it's $pristine, $error, etc, status when inputs are modified.

How can I have the compiled inputs be treated as part of the form?

This plunkr is an example of the problem I'm having:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tR7loK45wXEFcBIsDeur?p=preview

Comment: what's the point for doing this in the first place?  This doesn't feel like a very angular way of designing a page at all.  In this example, at least, your HTML string doesn't appear to have anything unique that couldn't be supplied in a template.  There are many ways of "dynamically generating HTML" with angular that don't involve `element.append`.

Comment: That's because it's an example. What I intend to do is to create a tool where you define your inputs in a json, and the tool mounts the html for the CRUD operations.

Comment: you mean something like this? https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form

Comment: yes, but I want to implement my own, where I define like this {name: 'phone_number', label: 'Phone number', show: true, edit: true, description: ['phone', 'required', ...]}

Comment: well, I'm pretty sure that project lets you define custom schemas, but if it doesn't, I would probably start with their code to see how they have done the dynamic form attachments.

Comment: to be honest, it doesn't make a lot of sense to re-invent the wheel and create your own schema definition unless there is a really compelling reason to; the [JSON schema project](http://json-schema.org/) is very mature and has covered multitudes of form configuration possibilities already.

Comment: But this is the only issue I'm struggling with. Actually, my tool WAS ready, but the HTML was too big, full of ng-ifs. I prefer doing it my way. For example, mine has support for form tabs...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87049/discussion-between-aleksandrus-and-claies).

Comment: you need your own, when existing wheels are bloated. have you tried using compile: instead of link: btw?

Comment: The established project uses transclusion and templates, and I still don't see why you couldn't use a template instead of an HTML string.  However, I suspect the transclusion is probably key for the form; you want your HTML to replace the existing tag, not be a child of your tag that the form doesn't support natively.  At the moment, plunker seems down.

Comment: YOU, I believe the problem this is not the problem. How changing the "link" to "compile" would affect the parent element (in this case, the form)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are doing is putting the element on dom after compiling it, and hence the ngmodel does not get a chance to hookup itself to the parent form.

what you are doing is:

```
1. create & compile element
2. place it in dom
```

as element is already compiled before making it to the dom.. it would never know of its parent form and hence wont link itself to the parent.

the sequence of step should have been:

```
1. create an element, 
2. place it in dom 
3. compile it. // now it will have a chance to hook up to the parent
```

so what you should rather do is:

```
   var el =angular.element('your html');
   element.append(el);
   $compile(el)(scope);
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Worked like a charm, and it was a very well explained!